Where do I get the best support on Solana related questions?
Where do I get the best support on Solana related questions, esp. Phantom? Solana itself refers to this website, but there are only few answers to the many users that have issues with the wallet. The Phantom Support (mail) takes ages to answer, and in their answer I get the feeling that I am talking to AI not real people,somehow like in the chat on their website. On Reddit it takes 30 days before I may write a post, on Discord the mod of the Solana group deletes my post (very friendly).

The best place for product support is the products official resources.
To get faster response - you can tag the company on Twitter.
This platform is for developers and technical questions.

thx, mate....am gonna try on X....I think the network is totally overcharged and a ton of new users coming in atm

It’s fine - you have still have to try - it’s your right as a customer
